# Chrome app executeScript with setTimeout, callback not waiting

Tags: javascript, settimeout, google-chrome-app

I am doing a Chrome app, and I am facing an issue :

I first inject a `file.js` in a Website open in a `<webview>`.

In this `file.js` I have a function which execute a return value include in a `setTimeout`.

The problem is when I call the function using `executeScript`, the callback doesn't wait for the end of `setTimeout`, and returns `null`.

Does someone could tell me what could I do ? thank you!

(Without `setTimeout`, it returns the expected value)

```js
//content of file.js
function foo(){
  setTimeout(function (){ return {key:"value"}; }, 5000);
}

//I inject the file.js in the website
webview.executeScript({file:"file.js"}, function(result){ console.log(result); });

//I call foo() in the website
webview.executeScript( {code:"foo();"}, function(result){ console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); });
```

Comment: If you are using a `<webview>`, this must be an app, not an extension. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes it is an App actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executeScript`'s callback will receive the last evaluated value of the script you run - synchronously.

You cannot wait for an async event (which `setTimeout` is).

Your best bet is to message the data back with [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).

Comment: YES, very good proposition, exactly What I wanted. In file.js, in setTimeout, I replace 'return ...' with 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage({key:"value"});. In myApp.js I put the listener chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request){ console.log(JSON.stringify(request)); });. Thank you very much Xan :)